# How can I output function results to pdf in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working in Jupyter Notebook and I have a function that generates multiple plots upon being called. I want to directly save all plots from this function call under one pdf. Is there ways to do that?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Alison

Comment: Have you tried JupyterLab/Markdown? You can plot all the images in the notebook and save it as a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PDFPages` to save all of your plots into a pdf. You can try the following example and implement it similarly in your code:

You can create a `plotGraph` function:

```
def plotGraph(X,Y):
      fig = plt.figure()
      ### Plotting code ###
      return fig
```

Then use that to get your and place them in your pdf.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

plot1 = plotGraph(graph1, label1)
plot2 = plotGraph(graph2, label2)
plot3 = plotGraph(graph3, label3)

pp = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
pp.savefig(plot1)
pp.savefig(plot2)
pp.savefig(plot3)
pp.close()
```

If you are okay with saving it as a PNG file with all the plots you can try the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
axis1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
axis1.plot(range(10))
axis2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
axis2.plot(range(10,20))
fig.savefig('allplots.png')
```

This basically creates [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) and saves all your plots in 1 png file.

Comment: Thank you! But if I do this, the three graphs are the same. They are all updated to be the last one. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the code you written to plot your graphs? Do you use the same template for each graph? You could try creating subplots instead of creating a whole function for it. I have provided an edited version which can save all your subplots as a single png file.